# Advantage of using IDisposable over performing actions in C# class finalizer

Tags: c#, .net

There are a lot of question discussing the "patterned" was of implementing and using IDisposable/Dispose, but what advantage does it have over having all the cleanup code in C# class finilizer?

Sure other classes can explicitly call Dispose earlier than the class instance is garbage collected and the finilizer is called. Is it the only one?

Comment: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167/1954

Comment: @TimSchmelter should be an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no guarantees about when or even if a Finalizer (destructor) will be called.

So in order to timely cleanup resources (Files, Db Connections) the Dispose pattern is essential.

Answer (score 1):

The IDisposable is made to avoid destructors.  The problem with destructors is that you never know when they are called, and objects with destructors are always the last to be cleaned up.

Using IDisposable you inform the user of you class that they should be using thwe using-method.
Eg:

```
using(MyClass myClass = new MyClass())
{
    // Do something with MyClass.
}
```

Comment: Not to avoid _having_ destructors. It avoids actually using (relying on) them.